# getopt with long options

Tags: sh, getopt

I have simple script to parse commandline arguments using `getopts`:

```
#!/bin/sh

 while getopts ":ab" opt
 do
    case $opt in
    a)
    echo "received option: a"
        ;;
    b)
    echo "received option: b"
        ;;
    ?)
        printf "\nunrecognized option\n\n" >&2
    exit 2
        ;;
    esac
 done

 shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))

 echo $@
```

This works as expected.

I need to convert it to use the non-buildin function `getopt` , so that it can take long arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

 while getopt --options ":ab" --longoptions "after,before" -- "$@" opt
 do
    case $opt in
    a|after)
    echo "received option: a|after"
        ;;
    b|before)
    echo "received option: b|before"
        ;;
    ?)
        printf "\nunrecognized option\n\n" >&2
    exit 2
        ;;
    esac
 done

 shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))

 echo $@
```

The above code does not work, it stays in endless `while` loop.

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I use `getopt` with longoptions in my script ?

Comment: For a working example, have a look at: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash

Comment: @John1024 - it says: "This script will only work with bash". My script is in `sh`

Comment: Yes, it says that.  On the other hand, I just ran `checkbashisms` on it and no problems were found.  I also run the script under the (lightweight shell) `dash` and it worked fine.

Comment: it "works" in dash, but I am not sure if correctly: `-b` is supposeds to have required argument. But when I run: `./misc-utils_getopt-parse.sh -a -b -c AAA BBB` it takes `-c` as argument belonging to `-b`. I believe, this all used to be taken care of when using `getopts`. That's why I would like to see my example adjusted for `getopt` with minimal changes.